# How get a specific key values from all randomId in realtime Database , Firebase functions using javaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all locations of my users for finding nearest friends

my Firebase Real-time database structure like

---> users

- ---> userRandomId

  ```
        --->  name:
               location :[12312,213123]
  ```
- ---> userRandomId

  ```
         --->  name:
               location :[12342,2143]
  ```

I want to get all locations inside each child when I call the function.

I tried:

```
var db = admin.database();

var ref1 = db.ref("users/{UserrandomiID}/location/");


ref1.on("value", (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
}, (errorObject) => {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

it returns nill always.
why it happens??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var db = admin.database();
var ref1 = db.ref("users");

ref1.on("value", (snapshot) => {
 snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=> {
    let location = childSnapshot.val().location;
      });
});
```

The snapshot is at `users` then loop inside the ids and retrieve the location.